# How to have GDAL print layers of GeoPDF AND say which are raster vs vector

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, gdal-translate, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

My Objective: I would like to use GDAL to convert a GeoPDF. I want the vector layers as shp files and the raster layers as tif files. I want to do this in a programmatic way.

Edit: In reality, I want to do this with many geospatial PDFs. I'm prototyping the workflow using Python, but it will probably end up being C++. (End Edit)

The Problem: Naturally, the command to convert a vector layer differs from a raster layer. And I don't know (again in a programmatic way) which layers are vector and which are raster.

What I've Tried: First, here is my sample data https://www.terragotech.com/images/pdf/webmap_urbansample.pdf.

```
gdalinfo webmap_urbansample.pdf -mdd LAYERS
```

gives the layer names:

```
...
Metadata (LAYERS):                           
  LAYER_00_NAME=Layers                       
  LAYER_01_NAME=Layers.BPS_-_Water_Sources   
  LAYER_02_NAME=Layers.BPS_-_Facilities      
  LAYER_03_NAME=Layers.BPS_-_Buildings       
  LAYER_04_NAME=Layers.Sewerage_Man_Holes    
  LAYER_05_NAME=Layers.Sewerage_Pump_Stations
  LAYER_06_NAME=Layers.Water_Points          
  LAYER_07_NAME=Layers.Roads                 
  LAYER_08_NAME=Layers.Sewerage_Jump-Ups     
  LAYER_09_NAME=Layers.Sewerage_Lines        
  LAYER_10_NAME=Layers.Water_Lines           
  LAYER_11_NAME=Layers.Cadastral_Boundaries  
  LAYER_12_NAME=Layers.Raster_Images         
...
```

I know to look at the data which are vector and which are raster, but I don't know how to parse this information to know whether to use ogr2ogr or gdal_translate to do the conversion.

Then I thought I could use `ogrinfo` and just diff all the layers to deduce which ones are raster, but `ogrinfo` gives me:

```
...
1: Cadastral Boundaries (Polygon)
2: Water Lines (Line String)
3: Sewerage Lines (Line String)
4: Sewerage Jump-Ups (Line String)
5: Roads
6: Water Points (Point)
7: Sewerage Pump Stations (Point)
8: Sewerage Man Holes (Point)
9: BPS - Buildings (Polygon)
10: BPS - Facilities (Polygon)
11: BPS - Water Sources (Point)
```

So there's not a one-to-one correspondence with the way these are output.

Does anyone know how to have gdal print the GeoPDF layers and indicate which are raster vs. vector?

Comment: Is there just one raster layer and the rest is vector? I think ogrinfo only lists those that it supports.

Comment: @bugmenot123 In this data set, yes. There is only one raster layer. If you're getting at the fact that ogrinfo won't list raster layers, then yes, that's what I saw too. I thought I might be able to leverage that fact to tell which layers were raster (because they won't be listed by ogrinfo). By "not a one-to-one comparison", I meant that the layer text is different, e.g., spaces vs underscores and the Layers.* syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the answer, but something I've been using as a workaround.

The script compares the text of the layers between gdalinfo and ogrinfo to infer which ones are raster. This approach isn't definitive though, so I imagine it could be wrong from time to time. Even in this example, `LAYER_00_NAME=Layers` isn't really a raster layer.

```
def GetRasterVectorLayers(filename):
    from osgeo import gdal
    from osgeo import ogr
    from difflib import SequenceMatcher

    # get vector layers with ogr
    data_ogr = ogr.Open(filename)
    if data_ogr:
        vector_layers = [ data_ogr.GetLayer(i).GetName() for i in range(data_ogr.GetLayerCount()) ]
    else:
        vector_layers = []

    # get all layers with gdal
    data_gdal = gdal.Open( filename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
    layers = data_gdal.GetMetadata_List("LAYERS")
    # peel off label, e.g., LAYER_00_NAME=Layers
    layers = [ layer.split('=')[-1] for layer in layers ]

    # match the text to deduce which layers are vector or raster
    matched_layers = []
    for vector_layer in vector_layers:
        layer_matches = []
        for layer in layers:
            layer_matches.append( [SequenceMatcher(None, vector_layer, layer).ratio(), layer] )
        layer_matches.sort()
        best_match = layer_matches[-1][1] # -1 gets the highest score, 1 gets the gdalinfo layer name
        matched_layers.append( [vector_layer,best_match] ) 

    layers_vector = [ match[1] for match in matched_layers ]
    layers_raster = [ layer for layer in layers if layer not in layers_vector ]
    return [layers_raster, layers_vector]

layers_raster, layers_vector = GetRasterVectorLayers('webmap_urbansample.pdf')

layers_raster
# ['Layers', 'Layers.Raster_Images']
layers_vector
# ['Layers.Cadastral_Boundaries', 'Layers.Water_Lines', 'Layers.Sewerage_Lines', 'Layers.Sewerage_Jump-Ups', 'Layers.Roads', 'Layers.Water_Points', 'Layers.Sewerage_Pump_Stations', 'Layers.Sewerage_Man_Holes', 'Layers.BPS_-_Buildings', 'Layers.BPS_-_Facilities', 'Layers.BPS_-_Water_Sources']
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, providing it actually provides an answer (which you do). The fact that you are already working with the Python API is important though, when I first read your question I expected you wanted something simpler (like a shell script). I'd add that to your question, as it opens more options.

Comment: Thanks - you're right, I should have included that information. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is up to the PDF creator how to name and number the raster and vector layers. New USGS Topo sheets are combined GeoPDF, and a sample file (`NM_Santa_Fe_20131108_TM_geo.pdf`) has this output from gdalinfo:

```
LAYER_00_NAME=Map_Collar   
LAYER_01_NAME=Map_Collar.Map_Elements  
LAYER_02_NAME=Map_Frame  
LAYER_03_NAME=Map_Frame.Projection_and_Grids
LAYER_04_NAME=Map_Frame.Geographic_Names  
LAYER_05_NAME=Map_Frame.Structures  
LAYER_06_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation  
LAYER_07_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation.Road_Names_and_Shields  
LAYER_08_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation.Road_Features  
LAYER_09_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation.Trails  
LAYER_10_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation.Railroads  
LAYER_11_NAME=Map_Frame.Transportation.Airports  
LAYER_12_NAME=Map_Frame.PLSS
LAYER_13_NAME=Map_Frame.Hydrography  
LAYER_14_NAME=Map_Frame.Terrain  
LAYER_15_NAME=Map_Frame.Terrain.Contours  
LAYER_16_NAME=Map_Frame.Terrain.Shaded_Relief  
LAYER_17_NAME=Map_Frame.Woodland   
LAYER_18_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries 
LAYER_19_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Jurisdictional_Boundaries  
LAYER_20_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Jurisdictional_Boundaries.International
LAYER_21_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Jurisdictional_Boundaries.State_or_Territory
LAYER_22_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Jurisdictional_Boundaries.County_or_Equivalent
LAYER_23_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Federal_Administered_Lands  
LAYER_24_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Federal_Administered_Lands.National_Park_Service
LAYER_25_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Federal_Administered_Lands.Department_of_Defense   
LAYER_26_NAME=Map_Frame.Boundaries.Federal_Administered_Lands.Forest_Service
LAYER_27_NAME=Images
LAYER_28_NAME=Images.Orthoimage
```

The layers are ordered hierarchical, with sublayers that have one or several points in the name. Layer 00, 02, 06, 14, 18, 19, 23 and 27 are meta layers, a combination of the following sublayers.

Ogrinfo reports:

```
1: Map_Collar
2: Map_Collar_Map_Elements
3: Map_Frame_Projection_and_Grids
4: Map_Frame_Geographic_Names (Multi Line String)
5: Map_Frame_Structures
6: Map_Frame_Transportation_Road_Names_and_Shields
7: Map_Frame_Transportation_Road_Features
8: Map_Frame_PLSS
9: Map_Frame_Hydrography
10: Map_Frame_Terrain_Contours
11: Map_Frame_Woodland
12: Map_Frame_Boundaries_Federal_Administered_Lands_Forest_Service
```

These are really only vector layers, but the substructure naming is lost, and different from your example the geometry type is only added in one layer. Both lists have no blanks in names (except the one with geometry). Meta layers and empty layers are omitted in the vector layer list. The numbering of the layers is not consistent (but not inverted as in your example).

If you want to extract all vector layers, you can use

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite out.sqlite in.pdf
```

If you try that with the GDAL raster commands, it will try to rasterize your vector data, which might take some time. So you have to include the raster layer name explicitely for every layer:

```
gdalwarp -co "TILED=YES" -co "TFW=YES" rumney_farmforest_geopdf.pdf rumtif01.tif -overwrite  --config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS "Graphic_Outline_(display_only)"
```

Comment: So I know how to extract the vector and raster layers. My question was how to know which layers are vector and which are raster so that I can extract each individual layer in an automated way. 
You point out that the substructure naming is lost, which I also point out in my question. Also, the difference in strings between the two calls (underscores vs spaces). I presume that gdalinfo reports the name of some object whereas ogrinfo gives an attribute value. Is there no way to make this uniform, e.g., through a certain api call?
I almost take your answer to mean there is no good answer.

Comment: The underscore vs blank does not apply to my example. I guess the GeoPDF driver still needs some developer attention, but there seem to be more important bugs to fix. The automatisation works for vector export into the spaitaöie database, while the raster layers need some handwork.