# To see the geodata in a PDF is necessary to process something first in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pdf, geospatial-pdf

I want to see if a pdf file has geographic data and how to access them. 
In the properties of the PDF document I see the pdf file was made in "AutoCAD Map 3D 2013," and have 6 layers.

In QGIS 2.14, when I add a vector layer, appears only 3 layers and the attribute tables only show the ID field. I read somewhere that something must be processed first to see more data but I can´t find it anymore.

It is true that to see more data is required to use some command in QGIS or process something?

Comment: Having such PDF document for testing would help a lot.

Comment: I suspended for now the use of this pdf file. I am now working with data from the OSM. If necessary go back and pick up again on the subject.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF file can have raster and vector data. On the command line (e.g. in the OSGEO4W shell) you can run `gdalinfo` and `ogrinfo` on the file to gather information on the layers that can be read by GDAL. See [How to have GDAL print layers of GeoPDF AND say which are raster vs vector](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156299/how-to-have-gdal-print-layers-of-geopdf-and-say-which-are-raster-vs-vector) for examples on that.

QGIS might hang up rasterizing a vector layer, so it might be a help to extract the sublayers with `gdal_translate` and `ogr2ogr` to formats that QGIS can read easily (GeoTiff, shapefile or spatialite).